# How to include HTML header tags in Django Crispy Forms?

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

I have the following HTML segment that I want to translate to django crispy forms:

```
    <div class="span5">
        <h3 class='offset1'>Select images</h3>
        <div id='image-drop' class='dropzone span5 center'>
            <p>Drag and drop photos and video here</p>
            <p class='big'>+</p>
            <p>Or click to add using the file browser</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

How would I include the  tag and

tags?  I tried this:

```
    self.helper.layout = Layout(
        Div(css_class='span5',
            HTML("<h3 class='offset1'>Select Images</h3>"),
            Div(css_id='image-drop',
                css_class='dropzone span5 center',
                HTML("<p>Drag and drop photos and video here</p><p class='big'>+</p><p>Or click to add using the file browser</p>")
                )
            )
        )
```

But this was giving a SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg --> pointing to the line with the HTML field.  Is there something wrong including HTML in Div?  How do I translate the given piece of HTML?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message is quite clear, isn't it?

So for example your inner block should probably look like this ([**args* fist, then ***kwargs*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3394898/630877)):

```
Div(
    HTML("<p>Drag and drop photos and video here</p><p class='big'>+</p><p>Or click to add using the file browser</p>"),
    css_id='image-drop',
    css_class='dropzone span5 center'
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but no, the message isn't quite clear to me.  No need to be sarcastic in your reply, it's bad for the learning community.

Comment: Sorry, i really didn't mean to be rude. Still i insist that the error messages gives a clear pointer to the root of the error `SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg`. So if you turn the error message into a question and ask _Where in the problematic chunk of code does a non keyword argument follow an argument?_ you are almost there. At least that was all i did.